# After I formatted my SD card as internal, how do I move heavy application to SD card?

Tags: internal-storage

I use instruction here to format my SD card as internal.

My phone is Poco X3 128 GB Xiaomi MIUI Version 14.0.2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOZIVbeNrxw

After I did it, I got an option if I want to move files to my SD card. I press yes and I go to files directory and I don't know what to do after that.

I check https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marc.files

To see my data are

It looks like the original SD card has been merged with my internal drive as if they are the same card.

However there is no way to know if the new combined internal drive has 256 GB storage instead of mere 128 GB

[image]

Another file manager shows that I have 128 GB storage. 112 GB storage actually

[image]

So it looks like I have 2 internal memory. Internal and Storage for Dual Apps. But they both have combined 112 GB instead of 256 GB.

I mean the whole point of internalizing my SD card is so I can have extra space. Where is the extra space.

The app files offer me an option to move the files latter. But how exactly do I do so? More precisely how do I move some large apps, like whatsapp, to that SD card so my phone can have extra spaces?

Update:
As for update, I can tell that I CANNOT store more than 128GB. Basically I got a message that disk is full.
So the extra space doesn't do anything

I cannot tell where the extra space go. I can't access my SD card anymore after what I did.